# What is the escape character for string inside $interpolate in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS. I have the following $scope variable;

```
$scope.text = $interpolate('<font color="brown"> <b> Press <Esc> key to escape</b></font>')($scope);
```

When it is rendered in the corresponding html, `{{text}}` does not have 'Esc' inside. I think there needs to be some escape characters for < and >. How do I make 'Esc' appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML Enitity codes for `<` and `>`, which are `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively:

```
$scope.text = $interpolate('<font color="brown"> <b> Press &lt;Esc&gt; key to escape</b></font>')($scope);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.text = $interpolate('<font color="brown"> <b> Press &lt;Esc&gt; key to escape</b></font>')($scope);
```